# sort ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> for 2nd entry of inner ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, sorting

I'm writing an app which has a part where it displays calendar events. It currently reads the first five events of all the active calendars on the device and puts them in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` which I'll name `calendarEvents` for further notice.
The entries of `calendarEvents` are `<"Title", "Start time", "End time">`. Those entries are sorted on start time **per calendar**. so

```
< entry 1 from calendar 1>
< entry 2 from calendar 1>
...
< entry 5 from calendar 1>
< entry 1 from calendar 2>
```

I want to sort those entries without respect to the calendar it came from. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: May be it's time to write `CalendarEvent` class?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and implement your [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class.